# Representation of Lie algebra $SE\left(2\right)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

When I read the paper [Universal approximations of invariant maps by neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10306.pdf) of *Dmitry Yarotsky*, it happens on *page 36* that he used some concepts about the representation of Lie algebra of the Lie group $\mathrm{SE}\left(2\right)$. 
Describe rigid motions of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by identifying it with $\mathbb{C}$. An element in $\mathrm{SE}\left(2\right)$ can be written as $\left(\gamma,\theta\right)=\left(x+iy,e^{i\phi}\right)$ with some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi\in\left[0,2\pi\right)$. The action of $\mathrm{SE}\left(2\right)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{C}$:
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{A}_{\left(x+iy,e^{i\theta}\right)}z=x+iy+e^{i\theta}z,\quad z\in \mathbb{C}
\end{equation*}
Consider the generators of the representation:
\begin{equation*}
    J_x=i\lim_{\delta x\to 0}\dfrac{R_{\left(\delta x,1\right)}-1}{\delta x}, \quad J_y=i\lim_{i\delta y\to 0}\dfrac{R_{\left(\delta y,1\right)}-1}{\delta x}, \quad J_\phi=i\lim_{\delta \phi\to 0}\dfrac{R_{\left(0,e^{i\delta \phi}\right)}-1}{\delta \phi}
\end{equation*}
The generators can be explicitly written as
\begin{equation*}
    J_x=-i\partial_x, \quad J_y=-i\partial_y,\quad J_\phi=-i\partial_\phi=-i\left(x\partial_y-y\partial_x\right)
\end{equation*}
and obey the commutation relations
\begin{equation}\label{eq41}
    \left[J_x,J_y\right]=0,\quad \left[J_x,J_\phi\right]=-iJ_y, \quad \left[J_y,J_\phi\right]=iJ_x
\end{equation}

---

I am a newbie in Lie representation. Can you explain to me the definition of $J_x, \partial_x$, the Lie brackets, and how these equations hold here? Or can you give me some books/papers defining these concepts? I looked upon the internet about the representation of Lie algebra but met nothing like these.
Can you help me please? Thank you very much.